# How to overwrite ref to remove rogue paranthesis?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

Reference to a figure adds a parenthesis at the end, how can I remove it or overwrite with a command?

When I then reference `see figure \ref{fig:examplefigure})` it becomes `see figure 1)`

I have a figure that looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{example.jpg}
  \caption{Example figure}
  \label{fig:examplefigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: by default `\ref` would not add parenthesis, just prints the number, so you have to not do whatever you have done in code not shown. Make a small complete test file and add it to your question so people can debug it

Comment: But you show `see figure \ref{fig:examplefigure})` it becomes see `figure 1)` which imples `\ref` is just making `1` and the `)` is simply text in your source???

Answer (score 3):

You show see

```
  figure \ref{fig:examplefigure})
```

> it becomes see figure 1)

which imples `\ref` is just making `1` and the `)` is simply text in your source which you can delete if you don't need it.